# C# How can I compare two date with sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite

I try to compare two date in Sqlite with my c# code and the comparison return the same value each time.. I don't know why.

I've two table with same value but one with download value and one with local value. I want to synchronise the two table. For that I use the date value "derniere_modification" and I update my temporary table temp_mres with true if I must save value and false If i must save online value.

My two code was :

```
>//On vérifie les données à mettre à jour dans la table de la tablette
>string sql = "UPDATE temp_mres SET synchronisation = 'true' WHERE julianDay >= (SELECT julianday(derniere_modification) FROM mres WHERE id = temp_mres.id)";
>SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
>command.ExecuteNonQuery();

>//On vérifie les données à mettre à jour en ligne
>string sql2 = "UPDATE temp_mres SET synchronisation = 'false' WHERE julianDay <= (SELECT julianday(derniere_modification) FROM mres WHERE id = temp_mres.id)";
>SQLiteCommand command2 = new SQLiteCommand(sql2, m_dbConnection);
>command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When I look my temp_mres table I write always true and never false in synchronisation.

My sqlite command look right ? Have you an idea about my problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: What values are you storing in these julianDay and derniere_modification columns?

Comment: Since It's updates true status , your sql query is right . So please check date values in DB

Comment: Date are to format datetime like this '1900-01-01' or '02-02-2018' in "derniere_modification" and in julianDay column I store day since independant day in this format ''2458498,5".